# A matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $L_A$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with entries from a field $F$. We denote by $L_A$ the mapping $L_A:F^n\times F^m$ defined by $L_A(x)=Ax$

A matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $L_A$ is diagonalizable.

$\Rightarrow$ If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix.

I don't know if I have to specify or construct a matrix to which $A$ is similar.

$\Leftarrow$ If $L_A$ is diagonalizable, then there exists a $\beta$ basis for $F^n$ such that $[L_A]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

Assuming that $m=n$, if β is any basis for $F^n$ and $P$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whose columns are the vectors in $\beta$, note that $[L_A]_\beta=P^{-1}AP$. How do I deduce that A is diagonalizable?

Comment: Assuming that $m=n$, if $\beta$ is any basis for $F^n$ and $P$ is the $n \times n$ matrix whose columns are the vectors in $\beta$, note that $[L_A]_\beta = P^{-1}AP$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Answering your last question: Isn't by definition?

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: What is the meaning of *similar matrices* for you?

Comment: $B$ is said to be similar to $A$ if and only if there exists a matrix $Q$, invertible, such that $B=Q^{-1}AQ$.

Comment: @azif00 From the above equation, as $[L_A]=P^{-1}AP$ we have that $A$ is diagonalizable, since it is similar to a diagonal matrix. Already have $\Leftarrow$, but still need $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $m=n$, otherwise the notation $[L_A]_\beta$ doesn't make sense. Also, denote the standard ordered basis for $F^n$ by $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$.

- If $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix, then we know that there exists an invertible $P \in \textsf{M}_{n \times n}(F)$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal. Define $\beta := (Pe_1,\dots,Pe_n)$. Then $\beta$ is an ordered basis for $F^n$ and $[L_A]_\beta = P^{-1}AP$.
- If there exists an ordered basis $\beta = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$ for $F^n$ such that $[L_A]_\beta$ is diagonal, define $P \in \textsf{M}_{n \times n}(F)$ by $Pe_j := v_j$ for $j = 1,\dots,n$. Then $P$ is invertible and $P^{-1}AP = [L_A]_\beta$.